# Call Google Maps Place ID when autofilling address

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to use this example from the google maps JavaScript docs. I cant figure out how to get a field I added called "place_id" filled with the place_id. Here is the code I'm working with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Place Autocomplete Address Form</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">
    <style>
      #locationField, #controls {
        position: relative;
        width: 480px;
      }
      #autocomplete {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 99%;
      }
      .label {
        text-align: right;
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 100px;
        color: #303030;
      }
      #address {
        border: 1px solid #000090;
        background-color: #f0f0ff;
        width: 480px;
        padding-right: 2px;
      }
      #address td {
        font-size: 10pt;
      }
      .field {
        width: 99%;
      }
      .slimField {
        width: 80px;
      }
      .wideField {
        width: 200px;
      }
      #locationField {
        height: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 2px;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="locationField">
      <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address"
             onFocus="geolocate()" type="text"></input>
    </div>

    <table id="address">
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Street address</td>
        <td class="slimField"><input class="field" id="street_number"
              disabled="true"></input></td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="2"><input class="field" id="route"
              disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">City</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" id="locality"
              disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">State</td>
        <td class="slimField"><input class="field"
              id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true"></input></td>
        <td class="label">Zip code</td>
        <td class="wideField"><input class="field" id="postal_code"
              disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Country</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field"
              id="country" disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Place ID</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field"
              id="results" disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <script>
// This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
// of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

var placeSearch, autocomplete;
var componentForm = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};



function initAutocomplete() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
  // location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
      {types: ['geocode']});

  // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
  // fields in the form.
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}

// [START region_fillform]
function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();


  document.getElementById('place_id').value = (place.place_id);

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }


  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
}

// [END region_fillform]

// [START region_geolocation]
// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: geolocation,
        radius: position.coords.accuracy
      });
      autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}
// [END region_geolocation]

    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBKvLBatUEiRAXevY4orDqmqBJp4jgtM7Y&signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
        async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you dont have a tag with id = place_id in your markup! anyways, please to send only necessary code and a fiddle attached. What does `console.log(document.getElementById())` return?? Remove all unecessay HTML and CSS, so you will receive more attention

Answer (score 1):

Since the input element for storing place value has id attribute named `results`

```
<input class="field" id="results" disabled="true"></input>
```

you could just change the line for saving place value to:

```
document.getElementById('results').value = (place.place_id);
```

**Modified example**

```js
// This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
// of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

var placeSearch, autocomplete;
var componentForm = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};



function initAutocomplete() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
  // location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
      {types: ['geocode']});

  // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
  // fields in the form.
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}

// [START region_fillform]
function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();


  document.getElementById('results').value = (place.place_id);

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }


  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
}

// [END region_fillform]

// [START region_geolocation]
// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: geolocation,
        radius: position.coords.accuracy
      });
      autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}
// [END region_geolocation]
```

```css
  #locationField, #controls {
            position: relative;
            width: 480px;
        }

        #autocomplete {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            width: 99%;
        }

        .label {
            text-align: right;
            font-weight: bold;
            width: 100px;
            color: #303030;
        }

        #address {
            border: 1px solid #000090;
            background-color: #f0f0ff;
            width: 480px;
            padding-right: 2px;
        }

            #address td {
                font-size: 10pt;
            }

        .field {
            width: 99%;
        }

        .slimField {
            width: 80px;
        }

        .wideField {
            width: 200px;
        }

        #locationField {
            height: 20px;
            margin-bottom: 2px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBKvLBatUEiRAXevY4orDqmqBJp4jgtM7Y&signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
            async defer></script>

   <div id="locationField">
        <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address"
               onfocus="geolocate()" type="text"></input>
    </div>

    <table id="address">
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Street address</td>
            <td class="slimField">
                <input class="field" id="street_number"
                       disabled="true"></input>
            </td>
            <td class="wideField" colspan="2">
                <input class="field" id="route"
                       disabled="true"></input>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">City</td>
            <td class="wideField" colspan="3">
                <input class="field" id="locality"
                       disabled="true"></input>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">State</td>
            <td class="slimField">
                <input class="field"
                       id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true"></input>
            </td>
            <td class="label">Zip code</td>
            <td class="wideField">
                <input class="field" id="postal_code"
                       disabled="true"></input>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Country</td>
            <td class="wideField" colspan="3">
                <input class="field"
                       id="country" disabled="true"></input>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Place ID</td>
            <td class="wideField" colspan="3">
                <input class="field"
                       id="results" disabled="true"></input>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```